# After Deploy/Publishing WCF server doesn't work

Tags: mysql, wcf, connection-string, wcf-data-services, publish

I have a WCF service that when I check in the WCF Test Client it works fine but after I deployed the service to a remote server(my college server) It doesn't work . I ran it on a wp8 app but it didn't gave me the errors so I ran it on the wcf test client and I found out that I cant connect to my DB  and I don't know why !

I search all over the web about connection strings because everyone told me that it is probably this but every thing seem fine :(

this is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbPulpoConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=PulpoDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PulpoDatabase.mdf"/>
```

I changed it also to :

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="dbPulpoConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PulpoDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PulpoDatabase.mdf"/>
```

but it still didnt work><

edit: In my propretise it says .NET FRAMWORK 4.5

please please help me I dont know what to do anymore><

edit: I have all the premisions I need On the remote server , on the remote server I have App_Data folder that my database.mdf files are in there and web.config and bin and the wcf.svc server

edit: my error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at IPulpoService.ShowStatistics(UserVO client) at PulpoServiceClient.ShowStatistics(UserVO client)
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using integrated security to access the database, you may need to use impersonation so the service will assume the client's identity when accessing the database. Otherwise, it will run as a local system account (or some variety thereof) which may not have permission to access the database.
To test this, you may try changing the connection string to use SQL Server security and put the username and password in the connection string, and see if that works. Obviously this is only a test - you should not actually keep your password in the file like that in a 'live' environment.

Comment: It didnt work I put the user name and password but it still didn't work